# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Response: [9] Cloud build status: FAILURE

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-cloud-deploy

Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build status: FAILURE
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/workspace/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

How do I solve this issue? I have enabled billing and have no other tasks in my queue
The error is coming from my app/build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
```